# How to disable further sorting after row edit in MUI Datagrid Pro

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm currently building a spreadsheet like project using MUI Data Grid Pro. I want users to be able to sort freely, so all columns are sortable. However, a users table may become very large.

A common use case for a user is to edit multiple columns at once on a single row. However, if they sort their table before editing their column, then edit the column that they are sorting by the row will move to it's new position in the table before a user can edit another column on the same row. The user then has to scroll back to find the row they previously edited, to edit the other cells. When tables get very large, this can be annoying.

I was wondering if there is a way to only sort when a user initially triggers a sort, then just maintain the row order of the initial sort, and if a user wants it to re-sort, they have to click the sort button again.

I tried to do a controlled state, and set the sort state to `[]` when a user begins to edit, but that just resets the initial table order. E.g:

```
const [sortModel, setSortModel] = React.useState([]);

const onRowUpdate = (...) => {
  setSortModel([]);
} 

const handleSortChange = (model) => {
  setSortModel(model);
}

return (
  <DataGridPro
    ...{props}
    processRowUpdate={onRowUpdate}
    sortModel={sortModel}
    onSortModelChange={(model) => handleSortChange(model)}
  />
)
```

I'm considering just overriding the mui sort, and actually sorting the data in the `row` prop, but that doesn't feel that clean and seems like it would add unnecessary renders. Is there a prop or easy way I'm missing to just not trigger a re-sort after a row has been edited?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue using DataGrid (MIT) v. 6.4.0. My general strategy to solve was, right before enabling the cell edit mode :

- return the grid to the first page and set the sort order for a specific column

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    ...
    setPaginationModel(() => defaultPagination);
    setSortModel(() => ([{
      field: 'zoneName',
      sort: 'asc',
    }]);
  };
```

- change the sortComparator of the selected column so the new row always appears first in the sort order, no matter the content entered by the user.

```
    const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    ...
    {
      field: 'zoneName',
      headerName: t('Zone'),
      editable: true,
      type: 'string',
      renderEditCell: renderZoneInput,
      sortComparator: (a, b) => isEditing ? -1 : (a < b ? -1 : (a > b ? 1 : 0)),
    },
    ...
```

The only drawback I found so far to this approach is the fact that during edition, the rows are displayed quite randomly, except for the first one that is edited :

[image]

Obviously, the sort comparator above can be improved.